# how to remove space around SvgPicture in flutter?

Tags: flutter, svg, flutter-layout

Whenever I add a SvgPicture somehow there is extra space that is created between the container, I have no idea how this space is being created.

I have tried changing the width and height, changing the actual size of SVG using Inkscape and changing the fit of the SvgPicture but something fixed the issue.

`IconButton(icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/drawing.svg'), onPressed: null)`
Here is the image of this code:
[image]

`IconButton(icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/drawing.svg', width: 15), onPressed: null)`

Here is the image of this code:

[image]

The actual SVG file has no space around it and is completely filled to the canvas.

Note: There is nothing inside the column except this SVG.

SVG CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="20"
   height="20"
   viewBox="0 0 5.2916665 5.2916665"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg882">
  <defs
     id="defs876" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata879">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <g
       id="g14"
       transform="matrix(0.01414769,0,0,0.01414769,0,-0.32822657)">
      <g
         id="g12">
        <g
           id="g10">
          <path
             d="M 327.6,67.6 C 320.8,42 297.2,23.2 270.4,23.2 H 59.2 C 26.8,23.2 0,49.6 0,82.4 v 98 C 0,208 19.6,232 46,238 c 6.4,25.6 29.6,44.4 57.2,44.4 h 8.8 v 59.2 c 0,3.2 2,6.4 4.8,8 1.2,0.4 2.4,0.8 4,0.8 2,0 3.6,-0.8 5.2,-2 l 85.6,-66 h 102.8 c 32.4,0 59.2,-26.4 59.2,-59.2 v -98 c 0,-28 -19.6,-51.6 -46,-57.6 z M 44,125.2 v 94 C 28.4,213.2 17.6,198 17.6,180.4 v -98 c 0,-22.8 18.8,-41.6 41.6,-41.6 h 211.6 c 16.8,0 31.6,10.4 38,25.2 H 103.2 C 70.8,66 44,92.4 44,125.2 Z m 312.4,98 H 356 c 0,22.8 -18.8,41.6 -41.6,41.6 H 208.8 c -2,0 -4,0.8 -5.2,2 l -74,57.2 v -50.4 c 0,-4.8 -4,-8.8 -8.8,-8.8 H 103.2 C 80.4,264.8 61.6,246 61.6,223.2 v -98 c 0,-22.8 18.8,-41.6 41.6,-41.6 h 211.6 c 22.8,0 41.6,18.8 41.6,41.6 z"
             id="path2" />
          <path
             d="m 298.8,122.4 h -180 c -4.8,0 -8.8,4 -8.8,8.8 0,4.8 4,8.8 8.8,8.8 h 180 c 4.8,0 8.8,-4 8.8,-8.8 0,-4.8 -4,-8.8 -8.8,-8.8 z"
             id="path4" />
          <path
             d="m 298.8,160.8 h -180 c -4.8,0 -8.8,4 -8.8,8.8 0,4.8 4,8.8 8.8,8.8 h 180 c 4.8,0 8.8,-4 8.8,-8.8 0,-4.8 -4,-8.8 -8.8,-8.8 z"
             id="path6" />
          <path
             d="m 298.8,199.6 h -180 c -4.8,0 -8.8,4 -8.8,8.8 0,4.8 4,8.8 8.8,8.8 h 180 c 4.8,0 8.8,-4 8.8,-8.8 0,-5.2 -4,-8.8 -8.8,-8.8 z"
             id="path8" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try using `Debug Paint` option in the `Flutter Inspector` tool. It will show you the exact boundaries of the widget. You can see if there is something wrong in it.

Comment: you may need to set a / a different viewBox attribute for the svg element. In order to get help please edit your question and add the code of an icon

Comment: I have added the SVG code and also I think I found the issue. the IconButton has ```Constructors
IconButton(EdgeInsetsGeometry padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0)``` Due to this padding of 8 and it is const. I think that's why there is extra spacing. You can find this in futter Doc.